# how to switch over from aspx to cshtml

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my old application I was using Default.aspx as the layout page for my ui-router. at the bottom of the page was:

```
 <form runat="server" style="visibility: collapse">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="mkt" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="id" runat="server" />
</form>
```

in my angular service i go the values with

```
 var market = (angular.element('#mkt').val() == '' ? this.marketAbbreviation : angular.element('#mkt').val());
 var id = (angular.element('#id').val() == '' ? this.sessionGuid : angular.element('#id').val());
```

both are string values being passed from a map application on modal launch. I've done searching and it seems this is a common issue. This is what I am trying to get working.

Index.cshtml

```
@model SubjectProperty.Web.Controllers.MKT

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.mkt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "mkt" } })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "id" } })
```

In my home controller

```
  public class MKT
{
    public string mkt { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(MKT m)
    {
        if (m == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var model = new MKT();

        model.id = m.id;
        model.mkt = m.mkt;

        return View(model);
    }
  }
```

now when I manually insert

> localhost:1323/?MKT=wet&Id=dd23e460-e319-47c9-b9c4-rr5r6798e56t

it picks it up and works. What am needing to do here?

Update, realized that the razor hiddenFor is not getting the values from the controller. here is a screenshot.
[image: pic]

Comment: how are you calling action?

Comment: on initial app launch. I am using default asp.net mvc application.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve here? Is there an error message you're getting with a particular URL?

Comment: no error messages. the model in the Index Action is coming in null. when I manually insert strings into browser navigation the model comes in with the values

Comment: Maybe I'm still missing something, but I still don't see the problem. If you're just using the URL localhost:1323/, where would you _expect_ the model values to come from?

Comment: ha! i see your point. sorry I confused myself. ok the problem is i see the values in the Index action. however I cannot get those values from the angular service.

Comment: what angular service? Sure looks like you are coupling a front end MVC framework too tightly with back end one. Why are you not just using angular stateParams to manage requests for data? Back end should only be used as an api

Comment: If you can inspect the page in your browser and verify that the model values are there (i.e. the lines `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.mkt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "mkt" } })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "id" } })` are working, then it looks like your question has nothing to do with MVC, only the syntax for getting your angular JavaScript code to read the values off the page. Is that accurate?

Comment: you are correct. i will check right now

Comment: how can i check in chrome console? I see where it should be but there is no elements there to open

Comment: Let's continue this conversation in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your hidden form fields inside a form:

```
using(Html.BeginForm()
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.mkt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "mkt" } })
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "id" } })
}
```

And also mark your method with the [HttpPost] attribute :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(MKT model)
 {
 }
```

If you want to use more advanced scenario, consider custom model binders.

Comment: the Post attribute causes it to not load anything. wrapping it in the form does the same thing as without it

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the HiddenFor's inside some kind of form (HTML, Ajax ...) and in your controller method's signature get the form elements collection like: `public ActionResult Index(FormCollection _collection)`

And prefix the method with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`

Comment: can you show little more on what to do in the action with the FormCollection

Comment: @texas697 you then use the Id of the form element (from the View) to access the collection:  DateTime.TryParse(_collection["txtTxTime"], out newTime);  or  if (_collection["txtTag"].IndexOf(" ") < 0)